# How to convert Objective-C line to Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have code in Objective C:

```
NSMutableArray* paths = [textView.textContainer.exclusionPaths mutableCopy];
```

and now when I try to convert it to Swift:

```
self.textView.textContainer.exclusionPaths(mutableCopy())
```

it gives me error:

```
Cannot call value of non-function type '[UIBezierPath]'
```

How can I convert it?

Also I tried:

```
self.textView.textContainer.exclusionPaths.mutableCopy()
```

but `exclusionPaths` does not have `mutableCopy()` method

Comment: You got the answers already! But, from my side check with this link. Even if you are face any issues converting Objective C to Swift, you can try with this site. Your answer is in following link: http://objc.to/pf1uhf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array(textView.textContainer.exclusionPaths)`.

Answer (score 6):

Simply do:

```
var paths = textView.textContainer.exclusionPaths
```

This will give you a mutable copy of the original array of paths.

Comment: I think these two answers are better than the accepted answer. It's cleaner and as a general rule, it's better to just use `var` and enjoy Swift's copy-on-write behavior.

Comment: In general, I agree that `var` is the way to go, but *in this instance*, where it's an Obj-C developer learning Swift, it's a lot clearer that my version is creating a copy. I strongly feel that Swift's immutable structs vs. mutable objects can be confusing, because you always have to keep in mind which one a given object is.

Answer (score 5):

In Swift declare a mutable type just with the `var` keyword

```
var paths = textView.textContainer.exclusionPaths
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. (Or rmaddy's, which says the same thing.)